# MAMP #2002 error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpmyadmin returns this:

> #2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2) The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).

Error message in mysql logs:

```
150706 00:12:40 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
150706 00:29:01 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
150706  0:29:01 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/ is case insensitive
150706  0:29:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150706  0:29:01 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Error: log file ./ib_logfile1 is of different size 0 5242888 bytes
InnoDB: than specified in the .cnf file 0 5242880 bytes!
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
150706  0:29:01 [ERROR] Aborting

150706  0:29:01 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150706 00:29:01 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

Keep trying to correct it, but MAMP's mysql server still won't start. Apache starts. Everything was working a few days ago. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`innodb_log_file_size` changed between the time you last ran mysqld and now.  This problem has been repeatedly answered.  I see at least one in the right column.